# $X_t$ measurable wrt $\sigma$-algebra and "revaled information"

Tags: measure-theory

Studying stochastic processes, it is mentioned that if $(X)_t$ is a process and $(\mathcal{X})_t$ a filtration, then if the process is adapted to the filtration, the informal way to think about it is that $X_t$ is known at time $t$, as stated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapted_process

I don't understand. How can this be the informal way to think about an adaption when it does not even contain any mention of the used filtration? Could somebody explain how this informal way to think about it arises?